When opening the door to access a cabin in a location prone to mosquitoes, how to minimize the likelihood of mosquitoes entering the place with me?
When opening the door to access a cabin in a location prone to mosquitoes, how can I minimize the likelihood of mosquitoes entering the place with me?

Have a screened in entryway.

Also make sure the lights are not on during that activity.  Mosquitoes will be drawn to them.

The most obvious answer: Be quick and keep the door open as short/as little as possible. Mosquitoes are not that fast, definitely slower than a fast walking speed. You could try to brush off mosquitoes sitting on you already directly before opening the door. If you are not alone, ask someone to help you with that.

If this is a serious problem in your location, in addition to sidling in rapidly as @Snijderfrey suggested in his answer, try spraying the door frame and lintel with insect repellent.  When I am reading or resting in a mosquito-y location, I spray the bottom of the rim of my hat with insect repellent.  The mosquitoes fly in for the kill, then, woops, veer off in an almost classical mathematical trajectory.
